# Can't connect to internet on Wi-Fi since update to iOS 7.1.1

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi

I recently updated to iOS 7.1.1 on my iPhone 5 and for the first couple of days everything was fine. Now, however, I can't connect to the internet on Wi-Fi.

The Wi-Fi is connected and the signal is there but when I browse on Google Chrome, access the App Store or even try iMessage it's not working.

Is this connected to the latest update? I've reset my network settings but that doesn't work, or switching the Wi-Fi on and off or switching the phone on and off. My 3G works fine.

Comment: After posting the above my 3G now seems to be playing up. No idea if that's related or it's just deciding to be temperamental now!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same EXACT problem when I upgraded my iPhone 4S to iOS 7. I had no wi-fi. I never got it to work, except, if I did the "freezer" trick with my phone, sometimes it would work for a little bit. This makes me believe it has to do with power use and heat.

I kept meaning to take it to the Apple Store to make them do something about it, but never got around to it. Then, when the latest iOS update came out, a couple days later, my phone started working fine again, and it has been ever since.

I think there is definitely something crazy going on with the power saving algorithms Apple uses. Did you get your iPhone 5 when it first came out? My iPhone 4s was one of the first ones. I stink the hardware changes during the production cycle, and sometimes us early adopters get left out when they start tweaking things.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Different. Posting in the answers section is specifically reserved for posting direct answers to the question being asked. The Stack Exchange Q&A format is different from your typical forum, it's not meant for discussion. For more information please see our [Help section](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help). Consider deleting this as it will likely continue to attract down votes for not being a direct answer to the question or improving it to be a direct answer.